# Laravel: Event Listener for table update

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using [Piwik](http://piwik.org) to track user visits on my site.

Everytime someone enters my site, the event is logged in the `Piwik` table and their landing page is stored.

I would like to create an Event in Laravel which listens for a changes to the `Piwik` table.  As Piwik is running outside of my Laravel app, I don't know how to create an event listener inside my app to perform this task.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Piwik has it's own API so it shouldnt be any problem to pull the new data on a regular basis (request them from your L4 app), it should suffice for your needs. http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api